# What online text editor can record macros?

Tags: web-applications, text-editor, saas

another valuable feature would be the ability to copy a vertical block of text

Comment: And I'm out of votes. This should be on webapps.

Comment: ok i added a webapps tag (I think that's what you mean) - thanks!

Comment: @geekzspot: No, I think Ignacio meant to move it to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/. (I flagged for migration.)

Comment: there you go: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57922/any-online-text-editor-which-can-record-macros but it will probably be closed there as well.